# How to rename a key in a JSON object using lenses?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm struggling with using the [at](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/microlens-0.4.11.2/docs/Lens-Micro.html#v:at) function along with the [key](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/microlens-aeson-2.3.1/docs/Lens-Micro-Aeson.html#v:key) function to change `{"foo": "abc"}` to `{"bar": "abc"}`

NB: I'm using the `microlens` family of packages, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

the `at` and `key` lenses serve to change the value of an Map-like object. If you want to change the key, set a new one with the value of the old one and delete the old. I don't have access to the compiler now so this code might not compile:

```
-- I think `at` can be substitute by `key` if your types allow it

--                                        |- sets the new key to the old value
--                                        |                |- deletes the old key
updateKey oldKey newKey myjson = myjson & at newKey .~ v & at oldKey .~ Nothing
  where v = myjson ^. at oldKey
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. `(undefined :: Aeson.Value) & at "mKey" .~ Nothing` gives the following error `No instance for (Lens.Micro.Internal.At Value)`

Comment: @SaurabhNanda sorry, what are you triying to do exactly? `Aeson.Value` is a json value not a pair `key: value`, obiously, you can't query a single value without key.

Comment: If the Aeson.Value contains an Aeson.Object then I'd like to rename a key.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda try both of this `(undefined :: Aeson.Object) & at "mKey" .~ Nothing` and `(undefined :: Lens.Micro.Type.Traversal' Aeson.Value Aeson.Value) & key "mKey" .~ Nothing`